# sharepoint 2013 Sp.Webproxy.invoke not include headers

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, yammer

I am working on a Sharepoint-hosted app that needs to call Yammer rest api with javascript. The access token has been obtained. Just need to pass it in the request headers. I have to use the sharepoint cross-domain library in the app.js. But doesn't matter how I tried, SP.WebProxy calls the endpoint without including that header. It turns out sharepoint intentionally ignores "Authorizatio" header. Does anyone know an alternative approach? Thank you.

```
function getYammer() {
   var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
   request.set_url("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/algo.json");
   request.set_headers({ "Authorization": "Bearer abcedfghijk" }); 

  //headers are not sent out to external service
  request.set_method("GET");
  var response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);
  context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);

  function onSuccess() {
    if (response.get_statusCode() == 200) {

        removePosts('yammer');

        var ResponseBody = JSON.parse(response.get_body());

        for (var i = 0, len = ResponseBody.data.length; i < len; i++) {
            vm.addYammerMessage(ResponseBody.data[i]);
        }
        sortPost();
    }

    else {
        var httpCode = response.get_statusCode();
        var httpText = response.get_body();
        window.console && console.log("Error code returned:" + httpText);
    }
  };

  function onFail() {
    window.console && console.log("Get yammer messages failed:" + response.get_body());
  };
```

};

Comment: I know that it is really old question but the reason why the header is ignored is described in documentation. The following headers are stripped off: Host, TE, **Authorization**, UserAgent, and TransferEncoding. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245145.aspx